# Creating a new list from two lists

Tags: functions

I have the two lists $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{a,b,c\}$. I want to get a new list $C=\{1 -> a,2->b,3->c\}$, which is just adding $->$ sign in between.

I tried

```
A={1,2,3};
B={a,b,c};
C={};
W="->";
Do [
 f[i]=A[[i]]*W*B[[i]];
 AppendTo[C, f[i]];
 ,{i,1,3}
];
```

But it is flipping the sequence in $C$ list. How to get rid of this?

Comment: What are you expecting the * to do?

Answer (score 5):

```
Thread[{1, 2, 3} -> {a, b, c}]
(* {1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c} *)
```

Note that the string `"->"` is different than `->` and multiplying isn't the same as inserting. Also, it is generally recommended to avoid using upper-case variables, as they may conflict with built-in symbols. In your case, `A` and `B` are safe, but you cannot assign to `C` because it is protected as a built-in symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you may also see `<| |>`

```
AssociationThread[{1,2,3},{a,b,c}]
```

gives an Association

if you do want list

```
AssociationThread[{1,2,3},{a,b,c}] // Normal
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Inner[Rule, {1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}, List]
```

> `{1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c}`

Answer (score 1):

Another minor variant can be:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
alist = {1, 2, 3};
blist = {a, b, c};
Rule @@@ Transpose[{alist, blist}]
```

> {1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c}